# I can't find 3D cursor Options

Tags: 3d-cursor

I am new to Blender an am following a course on LinkedInLearning 2.8. The tutorial mentions selecting the 3d cursor and then opening the Tools panel and choosing Options/ Align/ Geometry but in my Tools panel I only have Workspace showing. Where can I find Options?

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps the UI changed slightly, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Meanwhile, you can open Toolbar through *View > Toolbar*. There's *Options* dropdown in top right corner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it might be in *Object*> *Transform*> *Align Object*. You should have a popup right under your screen titled "Allign Object"

e.g.:

[image]

If I'm wrong, feel free to correct me!!

Note: select your object before aligning it

Answer (score 0):

I think the functionality you are looking for is this:
[image: ![![![enter image description here]

If you change this option in the Transformation Orientation menu you will move the object along an axis according to the position of the cursor rather than the global axis.

A good add on to enable is "Object: Align tools".  Under items, it gives you advanced options in the sidebar or aligning with the 3D cursor as well.

[image]f

Answer (score 0):

I guess the tutorial meant to set the 3D Cursor tool's `Orientation` setting to `Geometry`.

To access this, set the active tool to the 3D cursor by clicking the 3D cursor icon in the viewport's toolbar, then you will have access to that tool's settings at the top of the viewport:

[image: Active Tool's settings in viewport]

Alternatively, you can access the active tool's settings via the sidebar's `Tools` tab, or the Properties Editor's `Active Tool and Workspace settings` tab:

[image: other access points]